# Excel - Copy each value as many times as there are sequence numbers in another column

Tags: excel

I have the below dataset:

```
A B
1 Apple
2 Mango
3 Orange
```

And I'm trying to replicate each value of the B column as many times as there are sequence numbers in the A column (same sheet or another sheet doesn't matter):

```
A B
1 Apple
2 Apple
3 Apple
1 Mango
2 Mango
3 Mango
1 Orange
2 Orange
3 Orange
```

But I'm unable to come up with a way to achieve this. How do I achieve this without VBA?

Comment: Hello. Did you mean get job done with excel user functionality only? Two lines of python never did hurt to anybody :)

Comment: Excel worksheet functions can't write over themselves - this requires VBA (or other tool). Using excel, this would require helper columns and some trickery of sorts I suppose

Comment: How come "Apple" is copied three times, and not once?